# Sub Plots using Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot box plots and violin plots for three variables against a variable in a 3X2 subplot formation. But I am not able to figure out how to include sns lib with subplot function.

````
#plots=plt.figure()
axis=plt.subplots(nrows=3,ncols=3)
for i,feature in enumerate(list(df.columns.values)[:-1]):
    axis[i].plot(sns.boxplot(data=df,x='survival_status_after_5yrs',y=feature))
    i+=1
    axis[i].plot(sns.violinplot(data=df,x='survival_status_after_5yrs',y=feature))
plt.show()```

I am expecting 3X2 subplot, x axis stays same all the time y axis rolls over the three variables I have mentioned.

Thanks for your help.
````

Comment: I assume you mean `nrows=3, ncols=2` since you mention 3x2 subplot and your plotting code is trying two plot two plots for each feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two problems.

First, `plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2)` returns a figure object and an array of axes objects so you should replace this line with:
`fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2)`. The `ax` object is now a 3x2 numpy array of axes objects.

You could turn this into a 1-d array with `ax = ax.flatten()` but given what I think you are trying to do I think it is easier to keep as 3x2.
(Btw I assume the `ncols=3` is a typo)

Second, as Ewoud answer mentions with `seaborn` you pass the axes to plot on as an argument to the plot call.

I think the following will work for you:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2)
for i, feature in enumerate(list(df.columns.values)[:-1]):
    # for each feature create two plots on the same row
    sns.boxplot(data=df, x='survival_status_after_5yrs',y=feature, ax=ax[i, 0])
    sns.violinplot(data=df, x='survival_status_after_5yrs', y=feature, ax=ax[i, 1])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Most seaborn plot functions have an axis kwarg, so instead of

```
axis[i].plot(sns.boxplot(data=df,x='survival_status_after_5yrs',y=feature))
```

try

```
sns.boxplot(data=df,x='survival_status_after_5yrs',y=feature,axis=axis[i])
```